# Using math inside text (\ensuremath equivalent) in mathjax

Tags: text, mathjax

I am writing some maths notes in MathJax (in Markdown, if relevant) and want to be able to write out definitions in a `\text{}` block, but interspersed with some variable names.

In TeX, it is possible to do this (combine text and math) using `\ensuremath{}` e.g.

`\text{Then \ensuremath{x} is the solution}`.

What is the equivalent of this in MathJax? At the moment I would do `$\text{Then } x \text{ is the solution.}` but this is far from ideal. What is the best/correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in using `\ensuremath` in the latex version, the test for math mode it does will always fail (as `\text` content is never math). You can simply use `\text{Then $x$ is the solution}`

I just tried this it seems to work in mathjax as well, or use`\(` if you have not enabled `$` (mathjax setup not on topic here)

Using the sandbox linked from mathjax.org replacing 2 *a* in the denominator by your test:

[image]